# loop through files of helm chart and inject values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a directory structure like this:

```
helm
|-->mappings
   |--> foo
         foo1.yaml foo2.yaml
|-->templates 
     mapping.yaml
  values.yaml
```

where values.yaml
has a value that I need to be a variable due to environment like `{{ .Values.data.hostname }}`

and in mapping.yaml

```
{{- $files := .Files }}

{{- range .Values.mappings.foo }}
{{- $genericfilepath := printf "mappings/foo/%s.yaml" . }}
{{ $files.Get $genericfilepath }}

{{- end }}
```

Currently the mapping.yaml file loops through the designated directory and load the yaml file however I am unable to access the Values variable.

I have also attempted subchart where values.yaml file would be under helm/mappings/foo/values.yaml but it also doesn't resolve or I am not 100% understanding if subchart would be the correct solution to resolve the file path

Answer (score 2):

In the [Go `text/template` language](https://godoc.org/text/template), `.` is a special "context" variable, and references like `.Files` or `.Values` are actually retrieving fields from `.`.  For example, you could write a sample template:

```
{{- $dot := . -}}
# These both print the same value
dot-values-foo: {{ .Values.foo }}
dollars-dot-values-foo: {{ $dot.Values.foo }}
```

One of the ways `.` is special is that the `range` statement sets `.` to each item as it iterates through a collection.  In your example:

```
{{/* . is the top item; .Values is valid */}}
{{- range .Values.mappings.foo }}
{{/* . is one of the items in `mappings.foo` */}}
{{- end }}
{{/* . is the top item again */}}
```

If I need to use `.` for some special purpose like this, I tend to save the original top item in a variable, and then I can refer to fields in that.

```
{{- $top := . }}
{{- range .Values.mappings.foo }}
{{- $genericfilepath := printf "mappings/foo/%s.yaml" . }}
{{ $top.Files.Get $genericfilepath }}
{{ index $top.Values.enabled . }}
{{- end }}
```